# Multiple instances of an Activity - is this bad practice?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am creating an app which will have multiple 'grids' containing a title and image thumbnails in each grid square.

Each Grid will have different content stored in it.

I have so far created one activity that initialises an instance of GridView, and uses a custom GridAdapter. (See photo for what it currently looks like) I was planning to swipe left to create a new empty grid in which the user can upload content. There may be anywhere up to 50 grids.

I'm just learning how to implement the gesture, and how to create a new instance of the activity, but from what I've read, I am thinking I have designed it badly.

I was planning for each grid to be an Activity (each takes up the full screen).

I envisaged an Activity as being like a Class in java that you can create instances from a blueprint. I thought if I created one 'Grid' I could create a new instance of it each time. Fragments didn't seem appropriate at the time, as the android tutorials often described them as being purposed to add components to activities.

I'm starting to think though that I am using the wrong methodology here and I need to change it? Can someone guide me in the right direction? I have written all the code already - if I need to change it, do Fragments and Activities share any methods, meaning I can retain some work?

[image]

Comment: So, currently you are listening for swipe gestures and then starting activities?

Comment: Hi @Shaishav - that's the bit I'm just about to do. I have created one activity that initialises an instance of GridView, and uses a custom GridAdapter. I'm just learning how to implement the gesture, and how to create a new instance of the activity, but from what I've read, I am thinking I have done it wrong.....

Comment: I have tried to clarify it a bit better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you mentioned, using activities for holding content in your use case where switching may be triggered using gestures will definitely be resource heavy and cumbersome. Since, you mentioned swipe gestures, I believe fragments would be much lightweight in this situation. In fact, I would suggest you even look at `ViewPager` which even recycles fragments for you and optimizes user experience by loading the next fragment for a smoother experience. It will also handle swipe gestures for you!

**[UPDATE]**

Based on your updated explanation of the user flow, I'm certain that the `ViewPager` would fare as a better option mainly because it allows for a much better control and user navigation. It will also take care of handling swipe gestures and memory issues that come with these types of flows. Moreover, it will even allow for a page titles and bottom tab indicators in case you need them.

It will require each of its pages to be a fragment (your `ViewPager` will itself reside in an `Activity`). Once the user clicks on a grid cell, you can show a dialog window from where user input can be captured. This setup should be optimal for you resource wise in my opinion.

Comment: Hi @Shaishav. Thanks for helping me. So do you recommend each grid is one fragment, there are multiple fragments, and just one activity? So each time you swipe it stays on the same activity, but loads a new fragment? Each grid square contains a different View object. Would ViewPager work in that situation? I have added a photo above to help me explain. Thank you so much for your advice

Comment: @javapalava I guess, I misunderstood. I thought initially your layout will look like your image and then when the user clicks on a grid cell, it'd go to full screen and user can swipe left/right to check other cells in full screen. I'm confused, how will user interact with the image above. Whats the user flow here?

Comment: Let's maybe ignore the gesture element - I think I am confusing matters, and it is maybe not even relevant for what I am trying to figure out. There will be lots (up to 50) of these grids (however the user accesses them) stored in the app, and each will have different content contained within them. I have written the code for one, but now I need to enable the user to create many, and am just trying to figure out what should be a fragment, and what an activity.

Comment: @javapalava So, something like - The user sees the above grid which is [possibly] vertically scrollable and user can add more cells via, lets say a grid cell that has a "+" sign and enter its info. Clicking on any cell may show an expanded information about it. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: So, the user will see the following grid - it is vertically scrollable, but has a fixed length - currently only 5 squares long. So each grid has 15 squares in total (3 x 5). Users can't add more cells, they only ever have 15. They can click on a cell, which opens a pop up menu, and they can choose an image from their gallery, which is resized and stored in a cell. Once an image is in there, they can't expand it. Each 'grid' or 'board' will have a theme - i.e. thumbnails of family, house, etc. There will be multiple 'Grids' or 'Boards' - so lots like the one above.

Comment: They will all have different titles, and each will likely contain different thumbnails, but will have the same grid structure, as shown above. So there will be lots of that picture, but with different things stored in them!

Comment: I need to get better at explaining :)

Comment: Thanks so much @Shaishav! I've already done the dialogue window :) So, are you suggesting that each 'grid/board' is a fragment? And that each one shares the same Activity?

Comment: @javapalava great! Yeah each one shares the same `ViewPager` which would reside in an `Activity`.

Comment: OK great, will look up ViewPager! Thanks so much! Have lots of work to do :)

Comment: @javapalava Cool. All the best!

Comment: @javapalava If this works out for you don't forget to accept my answer. :)

Comment: Of course! You were a great help. I am just figuring out how to implement now :)